# Where to execute bash command in visual studio?

Tags: linux, bash, flutter, travis-ci

I want to setup CI for my flutter project, and i need to encrypt the keystore file. For this i choose the following solution: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/

I am developing with visual studio code, also i have no idea about bash. I need to execute following command:

```
$ travis encrypt-file super_secret.txt
encrypting super_secret.txt for rkh/travis-encrypt-file-example
storing result as super_secret.txt.enc
storing secure env variables for decryption
```

Questions:

1. Where do I execute this command? Currently i try to use the git bash, but that does not seem to work.
2. Is this command above "one single command" or should i execute every single line seperate?
3. I assume that git bash is the wrong place, what do i need to execute this in the right environtment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You execute it in your local command line - it doesn't matter which one really, but you have to taken care of the [prerequisites](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#prerequisites), meaning you installed the `travis` CLI and logged into your account. You also have to be in the folder of your project that already has Travis setup.
2. Only the first line is a command, the other 3 lines are output this command will generate (Commands are often prefixed with `$` to indicate that this should be input on your shell / command line and executed with [Enter])
3. See 1)